# zip/unzip functions in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I am looking for functions like zip/unzip in functional programming languages (e.g. Haskell, Scala).

[Examples from the Haskell reference](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zip_f.html). Zip:

```
Input: zip [1,2,3] [9,8,7]
Output: [(1,9),(2,8),(3,7)]
```

Unzip:

```
Input: unzip [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
Output: ([1,2,3],[2,3,4])
```

In R, the input would look something like this. For zipping:

```
l1 <- list(1,2,3)
l2 <- list(9,8,7)
l <- Map(c, l1, l2)
```

For unzipping:

```
tuple1 <- list(1,2)
tuple2 <- list(2,3)
tuple3 <- list(3,4)
l <- Map(c, tuple1, tuple2, tuple3)
```

Is there any built-in solution / library in R that implements these methods? (FP functions tend to have quite a few names - searching for zip/unzip & R only gave me results for compressing/decompressing files.)

Comment: `Map(c, l1, l2)` and `Map(c, tuple1, tuple2, tuple3)` I think - your R examples are a bit confusing.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Well, I think the answer is the `Map` function then if you are happy with it. Feel free to answer your own question below :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [purrr package](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/) attempts to provide a lot of FP primitives. `purrr`'s version of zip is called `transpose()`.

```
 L1 <- list(as.list(1:3),as.list(9:7))
 library(purrr)
 (L2 <- transpose(L1))
## List of 3
##  $ :List of 2
##   ..$ : int 1
##   ..$ : int 9
##  $ :List of 2
##   ..$ : int 2
##   ..$ : int 8
##  $ :List of 2
##   ..$ : int 3
##   ..$ : int 7
identical(transpose(L2),L1)  ## TRUE
```

`transpose()` also works on your second (unzip) example.

Comment: Nice saw this in a video a month back and couldn't remember the package it was in. +1

Comment: If I understand the question correctly (dubious), I think it'd be `l %>% transpose() %>% simplify_all()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is exactly what you're after but if it's equal length vectors you can conform to an array and then use split for either direction:

```
l <- list(c(1, 9), c(2, 8), c(3, 7))

m <- do.call(rbind, l)

split(m, row(m))
split(m, col(m))

## > split(m, row(m))
## $`1`
## [1] 1 9
## 
## $`2`
## [1] 2 8
## 
## $`3`
## [1] 3 7


## > split(m, col(m))
## $`1`
## [1] 1 2 3
## 
## $`2`
## [1] 9 8 7
```